# How to save value of dropdown in PHP without submitting?

Tags: php, html, dropdown

Is there a way to save the value of this dropdown list in a variable in PHP (no AJAX) without actually submitting the form?

```
 <p>
            Choose device type :
            <?php
            echo "<select name='device_type_id'>";
            echo "<option value='Select'>Select</option>";
            foreach ($dev_type_results as $row) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>"; ?>
        </p>
```

Comment: You can't save any value from client to server if you don't send the datas to the server. What's wrong with ajax ?

Comment: well u can do it with fetch or XMLHttpRequest those are default javascript libraries to send data

Comment: @Cid I am just new to PHP and when I look at Ajax it terrifies me. Ok if you can help doing it in Ajax, here is what I need: I need to access the selected value in two different pages, how can I do that using Ajax then?

Comment: Can you tell what you want to achieve? It's either Ajax/Fetch or storing it locally via cookies/local storage/session storage. Are you sure you need that value on the server?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot. Php generates your page, then the select method is implemented on the client's browser, not on the server (the server side php script is not running anymore). You need to submit the form and do another run of the php script, where you extract the value from the POST.

Comment: ok can you help me do it in Ajax? I need to access the selected value in two different pages.

Comment: The stackoverflow is not about doing a job for someone else. It helps when you encounter some issues.
I can give you a piece of advice, the easiest way for beginners is to use JQuery and it's .ajax() function.
Google it or read the documentation.

Comment: @MaxShaian I tried finding something useful, couldn't find anything. I am totally lost!

Comment: @mr.fartty https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
There is a bunch of real life examples. Good luck on this uneasy way!
You can contact me outside stackoverflow for help: https://t.me/vanguardkras

Answer (score 1):

Submitting a form, either through AJAX or directly, sends a request to the server side, in our case PHP.

If you want a server to receive any data, you need to submit the form.

The answer is NO. It's not possible with aforementioned restrictions.

Comment: can you help me how to do it using Ajax then? I need to access that value in two different pages

Answer (score 1):

No. Not in PHP unless you submit it, save it in db and fetch it on different pages. In order to have values saved on the frontend, you'll have to use a store or state common in React or Vue. Another way is to use javascript to save in localstorage, cache storage, IndexDB or a cookie. You can then retrieve your value from there

Comment: can you help me how to do it using Ajax then? I need to access that value in two different pages.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to pass if you do not need the value on the server is [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) if you do not need to save it across browser close or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) if you need longer storage

Page1:

```
$("[name=device_type_id]").on("change",function() { 
  sessionStorage.setItem("device_type",this.value); 
});
```

Page2:

```
const deviceType = sessionStorage.getItem("device_type") || "Not passed";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookie to save the data on client side then get it on server side.

PHP Code ( Server Side ):

```
if ($_COOKIE) {
    header('content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    print_r($_COOKIE);
    exit;
}
```

Javascript Code ( Client Side ):

```
document.cookie = "name=yourname";
document.cookie = "favorite_food=bakso";
```